# Python implementation for contains pattern in text

Tags: python, reinventing-the-wheel

This is an implementation of `contains`, which returns a boolean indicating whether a pattern occurs in text.

I encountered this question while I was implementing find_all_index. For example, `contains('abc', 'b')` returns `True` and `contains('abc', 'c')` returns `True`.

I ran the following unit test cases, and it passed against all test cases, so the code seems to be working fine.

[Implementation](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2849b3af4f2a9131445c6fbe8ae36b1b)

[Test](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c800e8a64927e00c19e397d2c3cad94e)

```
def contains(text, pattern):
    assert isinstance(text, str), 'text is not a string: {}'.format(text)
    assert isinstance(pattern, str), 'pattern is not a string: {}'.format(text)

    """create a pattern variable name """
    pattern = list(pattern)
    p_len = len(pattern)

    clean_text = list(filter(str.isalnum, text))
    t_len = len(clean_text)

    print("Searching contains")
    for i in range(t_len):
        # If the first letter matches, check the rest of string
        if clean_text[i] == pattern[0]:

            for j in range(p_len):
                if i+j >= t_len:
                    return False
                if pattern[j] != clean_text[i+j]:
                    break
                if j == p_len-1:
                    return True

    return False

def test_string_algorithms(text, pattern):
    found = contains(text, pattern)
    print('contains({!r}, {!r}) => {}'.format(text, pattern, found))

def main():
    test_string_algorithms(text, pattern)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you know about the `in` keyword?

Comment: I would be open to have more code review.

Comment: When Should I consider to start a bounty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PEP8 and readability

- You have a few great docstrings, there is no need for block-comments **and** docstrings.
- In `contains` you have this `assert isinstance(text, str)` but don't use it.

## Code changes

Your `contains(text, pattern)` could be a lot more simplified. Because contains checks whether a pattern occurs in text and returns a boolean indicating .

```
def contains(text, pattern):
    """Return a boolean indicating whether pattern occurs in text."""
    # If our pattern index is equal to our pattern length 
    # then we found a match and we can return True
    # If our current text character is not our pattern character 
    # and if we were checking for a pattern
    # If we have not found our pattern then we return False

    text_index = 0
    pattern_index = 0

    text_length = len(text)
    pattern_length = len(pattern)

    while text_index < text_length:  
        if text[text_index] == pattern[pattern_index]:
            pattern_index += 1
        elif pattern_index > 0:
            pattern_index = 0
            continue
        if pattern_index + 1 > pattern_length:
            return True
        text_index += 1
    return False
```

Answer (score -2):

**Advice 1**

`if clean_text[i] == pattern[0]:` You don't need this. Consider this version:

```
def contains_v2(text, pattern):
    for i in range(len(text)):
        do_continue = False

        for j in range(len(pattern)):
            if text[i + j] != pattern[j]:
                do_continue = True
                break

        if do_continue:
            continue
        return i;
    return -1
```

**Advice 2**

In your version, you do `clean_text = list(filter(str.isalnum, text))`. That is doing 2 things in a single function. I suggest you remove it, and if you need it in your version, you filter first, and only then pass it to your implementation.